# How can I rotate a text properly in xamarin android? (execute rotation first)

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

How can I rotate a text in c# android xamarin? If I use rotate: [this happens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aq0Kt.png)
I did read some similar question that maybe overriding textview helps, but how can I do this?

The problem is as you can see the in the posted image the width and height stays the same so it's still using the same space(this is visible in visual studio [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gz6jv.png)) however the rotated element occupies less space(layout_rowweight is not relative) and the text getting cut off.

What I want to achieve is to use layout_rowweight(or sg similar) to fill the fullscreen relatively. Do I have to override textview somehow?

**Basically what I want is to rotate execute first then every other property relative to the new rotation.**

```
    <TextView
    android:text="Placeholder 101"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:background="#F44336"
    android:layout_columnSpan="1"
    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
    android:layout_rowSpan="1"
    android:textDirection="?android:attr/windowTransitionBackgroundFadeDuration"
    android:id="@+id/textViewx1"
    android:rotation="90" />
```

Comment: What is wrong with what you've shown?  It clearly rotated the text.  What do you expect it to do differently?

Comment: You have rotated it 90 degree.If you want to rotate it more just increase the number.

Comment: Also your textview don't have `android:layout_width` and `android:layout_height` which are 2 mandatory fields.

Comment: @Jason I want the rotation to be executed(drawn) first and every other property second relative to the new rotation.

Comment: need  you to rotate it so that its width is the same as its original height, its height is the same as its original width, and the position of the control below it is still under it, not overlapping?

Comment: @LeoZhu 1. Yes I don't want overlapping 2. I want the width and height to take care the rotated text new width and height, but as far as my research going I think I have to create a custom textview for it which is currently where I am stuck : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53951930/how-to-use-a-custom-textview-in-axml

Comment: Is your text fixed width and height or is it dynamically set in the code and the code makes it rotate? If it is fixed, you could set it to rotate in Xaml and offset it by a certain distance

Comment: @LeoZhu It isn't fix it has to be dynamic depending on the text + screen.