# How to use a custom textview in axml?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I created a custom text view, but I couldn't find a way to use it I only found examples for java. But `com.yournamespace.RotatedTextView`, `com.yournamespace.RotatedTextView` and `RotatedTextView` doesn't get recognised.

I've created attrs.xml and added:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <declare-styleable name="RotatedTextView">
    <attr name="customFont" format="string"/>
  </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

Didn't help, the custom text view starts like:

```
namespace First_android {

  public class RotatedTextView : TextView { }
```

Any ideas or sources?

Answer (score 0):

You should use something like the following code in the `.axml` file:

```
<First_android.RotatedTextView
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:text="Test"  />
```

Comment: Error: The 'First_android.RotatedTextView' is not declared.

Comment: @Wtom193 Have you tried to clean your project and manually delete bin and obj folders then restart VS, rebuild your project?

Comment: If I delete those folders the project wont build because of missing dll.